# Unpack large files with gzip in PHP

Tags: php, gzip

I'm using a simple unzip function (as seen below) for my files so I don't have to unzip files manually before they are processed further.

```
function uncompress($srcName, $dstName) {
    $string = implode("", gzfile($srcName));
    $fp = fopen($dstName, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The problem is that if the gzip file is large (e.g. 50mb) the unzipping takes a large amount of ram to process.

The question: can I parse a gzipped file in chunks and still get the correct result? Or is there a better other way to handle the issue of extracting large gzip files (even if it takes a few seconds more)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

gzfile() is a convenience method that calls gzopen, gzread, and gzclose.

So, yes, you can manually do the gzopen and gzread the file in chunks.

This will uncompress the file in 4kB chunks:

```
function uncompress($srcName, $dstName) {
    $sfp = gzopen($srcName, "rb");
    $fp = fopen($dstName, "w");

    while (!gzeof($sfp)) {
        $string = gzread($sfp, 4096);
        fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
    }
    gzclose($sfp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Tested on a 1MB gzip file that extracts to 48MB
- before: Process time: 12.1447s, Peak memory use: 96512kB
- Your solution: Process time: 0.6705s, Peak memory use: 256kB

Thank you :)

Comment: You may get better performance by tweaking the number at the end of the gzread call.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: 20 times better is good enough, and will remain good enough for a very long time. I would have to be very desperate or using huge files to try and tweak this thing further :)

Comment: `while ($string = gzread($sfp, 4096))` approach may lead to such a bug: If the returned string is `"0"` (literal string that contains "0") then it will evaluate to false and fall out of the while loop. Too rare condition but it may happen some day. A better approach might ve `while (($string = gzread($sfp, 4096)) != '')`. In PHP, `false == '0'` gives `true` but `'' == '0'` gives `false`.

Comment: this function didn't work for me. it extracts a big file but all empty. if i use 'tar' from command line then it works fine.

Comment: I forgot about this answer until someone upvoted it just recently.  I've changed it to check for `gzeof` instead of just blindly relying on `gzread`, which *should* fix the issue @maliayas mentioned above.  I should add a check to make sure `$sfp` or `$fp` don't `=== FALSE`, but I'm lazy.

Comment: Just for more info : We can use `$string = gzgets($sfp);` inside the loop is someone wants to read file line by line

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzgets.php

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
function uncompress($srcName, $dstName) {
    $fp = fopen($dstName, "w");
    fwrite($fp, implode("", gzfile($srcName)));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

$length parameter is optional.

Comment: It seems as if this approach does the same as the original approach using a large amount of memory. The whole file is being read and held in memory.

Comment: are not loaded into a variable data file (similar to streaming). is not an object model where load the  object string. This example does not affect "php_value memory_limit". your example affects this variable in "php.ini" file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux host, have the required privilegies to run commands, and the gzip command is installed, you could try calling it with something like [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec)

SOmething a bit like this, I guess, would do :

```
shell_exec('gzip -d your_file.gz');
```

This way, the file wouldn't be unzip by PHP.

As a sidenote :

- Take care where the command is run from (ot use a swith to tell "decompress to *that* directory")
- You might want to take a look at [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) too ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I do have shell access, but have yet to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As [maliayas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229571/unpack-large-files-with-gzip-in-php#comment22861084_1229696) mentioned, it may lead to a bug. I experienced an unexpected fall out of the while loop, but the gz file has been decompressed successfully. The whole code looks like this and works better for me:

```
function gzDecompressFile($srcName, $dstName) { 
    $error = false; 

    if( $file = gzopen($srcName, 'rb') ) { // open gz file

        $out_file = fopen($dstName, 'wb'); // open destination file

        while (($string = gzread($file, 4096)) != '') { // read 4kb at a time   
            if( !fwrite($out_file, $string) ) { // check if writing was successful
                 $error = true;
            }   
        }

        // close files
        fclose($out_file);
        gzclose($file);     

    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if ($error)
        return false; 
    else
        return true; 
}
```